# How to search values within a cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working with a large amount of data and am trying to enter standardized formulas to repeatedly convert to a more comprehensive version. What I'm having trouble with now is identifying each of these tiers of addresses and assigning a label. I'm stuck on the zip codes now. I want to be able to search each cell in this column for a 3-digit # vs a 5-digit #. I've been online searching all morning and most of the formulas I can find count the # of cells vs counting **within** an individual cell -- or -- apply to Excel. Any help would be greatly appreciated

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

if you want to extract the digits from each cell:

```
=index(ifna(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, "\d+")*(B2:B<>"")))
```

if you want to know the number of digits of each zip:

```
=index(ifna(len(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, "\d+")*(B2:B<>""))))
```

[image: digits]

Comment: Can you advise how I could work that into a formula where I could isolate that # of digits, IF=3, then ="3 Zip"?

Comment: use the second formula without an IF, but with: & " Zip" at its end, something like:                                                                                 =index(ifna(len(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, "\d+")*(B2:B<>""))&" Zip"))

Answer (score 0):

You can test the data for various patterns using `ifs()` and `regexmatch()`,  like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  ifs( 
    regexmatch(trim(B3:B), "(^|[^\d])\d{5}\s*.\s*\d{4}([^\d]|$)"), 
      "ZIP+4 code", 
    regexmatch(trim(B3:B), "(^|[^\d])\d{5}([^\d]|$)"), 
      "ZIP code", 
    regexmatch(trim(B3:B), "(^|[^\d])\d{3}([^\d]|$)"), 
      "sectional center facility code", 
    true, 
      iferror(1/0) 
  ) 
)
```

To learn the exact [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) syntax used by Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)